# How to map keys of JavaPairRDD in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and  I have used `sc.wholeTextFiles(path);` to read all files, the function returns `JavaPairRDD<String, String>` and Key of RDD is the full path to each file however what I want is to change the key to the name of the file.
Is their something like `mapValues(func)` but for keys.

Comment: can't you apply map operation on sc.wholeTextFiles(path) and convert  full path to just file name??

Comment: @shekhar map function will return JavaRDD

Comment: no, you can modify only key using .map operation.

Comment: @shekhar excuse me but the documentation says Return a new RDD by applying a function to all elements of this RDD which mean i will lose keys in that case.

Comment: I use scala, in scala map function works well for both rdd and pairedRDD, In java I think there is mapToPair function

Comment: you can refer https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/JavaWordCount.java

Answer (score 3):

The key assumption here is that `JavaPairRDD<String, String>` is the same as `JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>>`.

In other words `JavaPairRDD` is just `RDD` of tuples. So you can use the the common `map` to modify just the tuple key and leave the value untouched.

```java
JavaPairRDD<String, String> input = sc.wholeTextFiles(path);
input.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, Tuple2<String,String>>() {
  @Override
  public Tuple2<String, String> call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple) {
    return new Tuple2<>(convertToFilename(tuple._1()), tuple._2());
  }
});
```