# Parsing multiple files into SparkRDD

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, bigdata, rdd

We have multiple files with a data structure like:

**file1.txt**

```
idUser: 34 
Name: User1
Activity: 34 
Comments: I like this 

idUser: 45
Name: User43
Activity: 12 
Comments: I don'y like this activity
```

**file2.txt**

```
idUser: 45
Name: User43
Activity: 678
Comments: I like this activity but not much
```

We can have thousands of files and millions of records. We are planning to do data analysis in Spark with those files.

I have loaded my files like:

```
 JavaPairRDD<String, String> files = context.wholeTextFiles(inputPath);
```

I would like to transform this data structure to `JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<UserActivity>`

Where user activity is the entries in each file. Anyone knows how to do this transformation? Does anyone know to do it faster and using partitioning because I have more than 500 millions records?

Comment: You haven't described what `UserActivity` is in the question. Also, why exactly are you using `zipWithIndex`?

Comment: The `UserActivity` is the Object that contains the following information `idUser: 34 
Name: User1
Activity: 34 
Comments: I like this `  . . we used the zipWithIndex for faster reading.

Comment: You use `zipWithIndex` for faster reading? That makes no sense to me... Anyway, I would recommend that you look into `reduceByKey` to achieve your goal :)

Comment: The main problem I have now is that when you read the PairRDD you get a String, String object name of the file, all the content of the file in one line. IS the way to parse the content using split("\n") to get the UserActivity Objects?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want a `JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<UserActivity>>`? Don't you think that `JavaPairRDD<Integer, UserActivity>` would be enough? I think it will allow you to avoid many problems latter on.

If you want to transform a JavaPairRDD in another JavaPairRDD  you can use a map, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047520/how-to-map-keys-of-javapairrdd-in-spark)

Comment: the problem is that this Integer will allow me to do processing at User level that would be great for performance. I think?. Because I can use the granularity of the users to perform some specific algorithms only to some type of users. Make sense for you?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand correctly. But if your integer represents a User then having a JavaPairRDD<Integer, UserActivity> is no problem. You just need to us a filter function on your JavaPairRDD. The problem of using a JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<UserActivity>> is that you forbid spark to handle the data the way it wants. You oblige it to have a lot of data on the same partition. What if you have a user with 10 UserActivity and another with thousands. Those thousands will have to be on only one partition I think.

Comment: But this will make my algorithms faster no? if 1000 in the same partition rather that distributed.

Comment: No, because you will have to treat one element at a time

Comment: I have used now the JavaPairRDD<Integer, UserActivity> and it works great. @Arthur do you have experience for structured data to use newAPIHaoopFile with inputFormatClass. This helps Hadoop to create the reading block using the structured data. ?

Comment: Sorry I have never used that maybe [this](http://baahu.in/spark-java-code-to-read-files-with-custom-record-delimiter/) can help you.

Comment: Looks like the Spark is well documented by CSV, JSON and parquet and TXT but not for another type of text structured data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert JavaPairRDD data structure, to a JavaPairRDD with a different data structure, you can do it using the `.mapToPair()` command.

For example:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<UserActivity>> newStruct = files.mapToPair(new MyConverter());

public class MyConverter implements PairFunction<Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, Long>, Integer, List<UserActivity>> {
    public Tuple2<Integer, List<UserActivity>> call(Tuple2<Tuple2<<String, String>, Long> val) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Additional examples:

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD&method=mapToPair

**Update:**

The question was updated, so I'm updating my answer. With the current structure, it would look like:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, List<UserActivity>> newStruct = files.mapToPair(new MyConverter());

public class MyConverter implements PairFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, Integer, List<UserActivity>> {
    public Tuple2<Integer, List<UserActivity>> call(Tuple2<String, String> val) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @alexM if I remove the zipWithIndex can you update your example.

Comment: Just add an update to your question, and I will add an update to my answer. @ypriverol

Comment: I have updated my question removing the zipWithIndex .

Comment: @ypriverol But now your result (files) should be JavaRDD, not JavaPairRDD (and have a different structure).

Comment: Yes is true, I have changed already to a `JavaPairRDD<String, String>`

Comment: @ypriverol I've update it (also fixed a bug in my syntax)

Comment: Hi @Alex I have been reading more about the topic and apparently for structured data is better to extend the Hadoop FileInputFormat. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157809/discussion-between-alexm-and-ypriverol).